# Make a C programming language array in LaTeX

Tags: tables, programming

Im wondering if I can do some kind of table in LaTeX in order to show my C array nicely in text? I did something like this in KolourPaint:

[image]

Tried to do the same with LaTeX tables, but with no success ... Is it even possible?

I have only something like this so far (not very impressive, I know):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{tab[0]  tab[1]}\\ \hline
    123 & 23 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share with us the table that proves "unsuccessful" with `\documentclass` and everything :)

Comment: @zeroth: ok, will add the example but its not much of it :(

Comment: @BrianBrown Why the `\multicolumn`?

Comment: @Manuel I'd guess to remove the vertical rules, but this is never going to be lined up correctly in a clean way.

Comment: @hugovdberg Okey, didn't imagine that.

Comment: @BrianBrown you could try a `TikZ/pgf` picture, with the `matrix` library, I think that's the easiest way to line up everything automatically, and `TikZ` provides a lot of anchors in a matrix as handles for the lines.

Comment: What is it from the diagram that you're most hoping to emulate?  Is it the background shading?

Comment: @jon: no, Im not concerned about the shade at all. Just dont know how to align everything properly :/

Comment: How are they (to be) aligned?  The picture looks a little inconsistent.

Comment: @jon: its because I made it with KolourPaint... What I need is to align them in 3 rows and 8 columns, but dont want to have any "lines" between elements in first and last row and above/below them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is far from okey. But it works. I hope someone comes with a more automatized version (I would *even* prefer TikZ for this over my solution).
**EDIT** I was silly enough to make first and last line with `\multicolumn` while it's easier to use it just in the middle row. I keep this unchanged, since I'm not fond (:P) of this solution.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{a} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{b} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{c} \\ \hline
    c & d & e \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{e} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{f} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{g}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And here goes something to play with [`tap`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164925/is-there-a-tool-to-make-a-complicated-table-like-this-one-auswahlliste-from/165374#165374), which can break some things as it mixes Plain Tex with Latex, but… I like the output (I also used it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166104/centering-individual-cells-in-booktabs/166153#166153)).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\input{tap}

\begin{document}
\begintable
    \begintableformat
        & \center
    \endtableformat
    \B": \texttt{tab[0]} " \texttt{tab[1]} " \texttt{tab[2]} " \texttt{tab[3]} " \texttt{tab[4]} " \texttt{tab[5]} " \texttt{tab[6]} " \texttt{tab[7]} \E"
    \=
    \B!: 1234 ! 56 ! 1212 ! 33 ! 1434 ! 80 ! 1312 ! 78 \E!
    \=
    \B": 65508 " 65510 " 65512 " 65514 " 65516 " 65518 " 65520 " 65522 \E"
\endtable
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, no, don't accept this. I think someone will come up with a better, cleaner, and more automatized solution.

Comment: Just rewrite the `\mutlicolumn` commands so you can just do something like `\mcs{<text>}` instead of `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsf{#1}}` every time...  (Never heard of `tap` before!)

Comment: @jon That's true, but I meant something like Sean Allred solution or even something like `\begin{Carray} a & b & c \\ c & d & e \\ e & f & g \end{Carray}` to get the exact ouput as mine. **EDIT:** About `tap` I like its flexibility, I hope someone with the necessary skills translates it to “Latex”. It's similar to the Context approach, I think.

Comment: Well, it's true that I'd use `multicolumn` on the 'box' line (as Sean's answer does); but LaTeX does not have good 'row' support by default.  ConTeXt would handle this problem much more easily with the `\setupTABLE` command (forget the exact name).

Answer (score 16):

Consider using something plainer, like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { brian / c-array } {
  name         .tl_set:N = \l_brian_c_array_name_tl,
  name-fmt     .tl_set:N = \l_brian_c_array_name_fmt_tl,
  index-start .int_set:N = \l_brian_c_array_index_int,
  addr-start  .int_set:N = \l_brian_c_array_addr_int,
  addr-step   .int_set:N = \l_brian_c_array_addr_step_int,
  addr-fmt     .tl_set:N = \l_brian_c_array_addr_fmt_tl,
  inner-fmt    .tl_set:N = \l_brian_c_array_inner_fmt_tl,
  top-skip    .dim_set:N = \l_brian_c_array_top_skip_dim,
  bottom-skip .dim_set:N = \l_brian_c_array_bottom_skip_dim,
  inner-strut  .tl_set:N = \l_brian_c_array_inner_strut_tl,
}

\cs_new:Nn \__brian_temp:n{
  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{
    \l_brian_c_array_inner_fmt_tl
    #1
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \CArray { O{} m O{\rule[-2.25ex]{0pt}{6ex}}} {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn
    { brian / c-array }
    { name=arr,
      name-fmt=\ttfamily\small,
      index-start=0,
      addr-start=2000,
      addr-step=4,
      top-skip = \medskipamount,
      bottom-skip = 3ex,
      inner-strut = \rule[-2.25ex]{0pt}{6ex},
      inner-fmt = \rmfamily,
      addr-fmt = \rmfamily,
      #1 }

  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #2 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN   \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq }


  \begin{tabular}{*{\int_eval:n { \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq + 1 }}{c}}
    \tl_use:N \l_brian_c_array_name_fmt_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_brian_c_array_name_tl
    [\int_use:N \l_brian_c_array_index_int]
    \prg_replicate:nn {\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int}
      { 
        &
        \int_gincr:N \l_brian_c_array_index_int
        \tl_use:N \l_brian_c_array_name_fmt_tl
        \tl_use:N \l_brian_c_array_name_tl
        [\int_use:N \l_brian_c_array_index_int]
      }
      \\[\l_brian_c_array_top_skip_dim]
      \hline

      \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{
        \l_brian_c_array_inner_strut_tl
        \l_brian_c_array_inner_fmt_tl
        \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
      }
      \seq_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_seq \__brian_temp:n
      \\
      \hline
      \rule{0pt}{\l_brian_c_array_bottom_skip_dim}
      \l_brian_c_array_addr_fmt_tl
      \int_use:N \l_brian_c_array_addr_int
      \prg_replicate:nn { \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int }
        {
          & \int_gadd:Nn \l_brian_c_array_addr_int
              {
                \int_use:N \l_brian_c_array_addr_step_int
              }
            \l_brian_c_array_addr_fmt_tl
            \int_use:N \l_brian_c_array_addr_int
        }
  \end{tabular}

  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\centering

\CArray[
addr-start=65508,
addr-step=4,
name=tab,
name-fmt=\ttfamily\small,
inner-fmt=\ttfamily,
]{1234, 56, 1212, 33, 1434, 80, 1312, 78}

\vspace{1in}

\CArray[inner-fmt=\ttfamily\large,name-fmt=\ttfamily]
{1,2,3}
\end{document}
```

If you really want the tabular shadow, I can edit that in. (I need to figure out how to do it, first `:)`)

<sub>A big thanks to [@hugovdberg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/46598/hugovdberg) and [@egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) for [sorting out the intermediate snafoo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169441/17423) with `\seq_map_…:`. `:)`</sub>

Comment: nice! its very kind of you, but dont bother yourself with the shadow ;) I can live without it :P cheers!

Comment: @BrianBrown See my edit :) And for shadows, you might want to check out the `fancybox` package. I'm not sure how useful it could be in this implementation, but it's worth a look.  (At the very least, you can wrap the whole thing in a `\shadowbox`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu51O.png)