# How can I combine \seq_use:Nn and \seq_map_inline:Nn?

Tags: expl3

The following 'naïve' solution throws the error:

> ```
> ERROR: Misplaced \omit.
>
> --- TeX said ---
> \multispan ->\omit 
>                    \@multispan 
> l.13   }
>          \\
> --- HELP ---
> From the .log file...
>
> I expect to see \omit only after tab marks or the \cr of
> an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.
> ```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { 1 , 2 , 3 }

\begin{tabular}{*{\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq}{c}}
  hellow & world \\
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{#1} &
  } \\
  goodbye & world
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

where I'd like to come up with a table like:

```
  hello    world
|   1    |   2   | 3 |
 goodbye   world
```

What's the most efficient / clearest way to go about this?

Comment: Isn't this caused (as the help tells you) by an unequal number of items in each row? You have 2 cells in the first row, and then write a sequence of three cells to the second. Perhaps add an `&` to the first and last row?

Comment: @hugovdberg The error message is clear, but you actually don't need an equal number of items in each row `:)` as long as you don't make more columns than you specify, you're ok.  The question is more to get the result I'm going for, not necessarily to fix the code I have. I'm fairly certain my approach will turn out to be utterly fruitless `:(`

Comment: and what about a newline after the `\seq_map_inline` and an extra `&` after the third item? You have 3 items, each with a `&` so specifying 4 cells in that row actually, while a count of the sequence returns 3. Perhaps a conditional `if items < count insert &`?

Comment: @hugovdberg Ah yes, that's a typo `:)` see my edit

Comment: It's a problem of expandability.  `\seq_map_inline:Nn` is not expandable.  You can use `\seq_map_function:NN` after defining a (non-protected) function which does `\multicolumn{...}{...}{#1}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use an expandable function, because any unexpandable token makes `\multicolumn` illegal after it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { 1 , 2 , 3 }
\seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
\cs_new:Npn \sean_add_mc:n #1
 {
  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}
 }

\begin{tabular}{*{\int_eval:n { \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq + 1 }}{c}}
  hellow & world & some \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\l_tmpa_tl}
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_seq \sean_add_mc:n \\
  goodbye & world & again
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Note that the first item should be detached because it needs a different treatment.

[image]