# Automatic generation of table that shows groupings

Tags: tables, expansion, multicolumn

In my document, I'm using one command to create numbered elements and another command to group all elements up to the next grouping command. I'm trying to create a table that shows these groupings, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}    

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{0.9cm}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}    

\newcounter{Elements}
\setcounter{Elements}{1}    

\newcommand{\newgrouping}[1]{#1 starts.\\}
\newcommand{\newelement}{Element \theElements.\\ \addtocounter{Elements}{1}}    

\begin{document}
\newgrouping{Some}
\newelement
\newelement
\newgrouping{Stuff}
\newelement
\newelement
\newelement
\newgrouping{Here}
\newelement    

First table:
\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|}
\hline
\begin{tabularx}{2cm}{Y|Y} 1 & 2 \end{tabularx} & \begin{tabularx}{2cm}{Y|Y|Y} 3 & 4 & 5 \end{tabularx} & \begin{tabularx}{2cm}{Y} 6 \end{tabularx} \\
\hline
Some & Stuff & Here \\ \hline
\end{tabular}    

\vspace{3em}
Second table:
\begin{tabular}{|x|x|x|x|x|x|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Some} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Stuff} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Here} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}    

\end{document}
```

You can see the output in this image:
[image: Output from code with tables]

In the above code, the tables are hard-coded. I want them to automatically adapt to new groupings and elements. I would prefer the first table version, but since I believe the second version is somewhat simpler, I post my unfinished code for building the second table version.

With the help of some other posts, I got this far (code should compile). Now I'm unable to create the second row of the table automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}    

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{0.9cm}}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{\expand}{}
\long\@namedef{NC@rewrite@\string\expand}{\expandafter\NC@find}
\makeatother    

\newcounter{Elements}
\setcounter{Elements}{1}    

\newcounter{ElementsInGroup}
\setcounter{ElementsInGroup}{0}
\newcounter{GroupNumber}
\setcounter{GroupNumber}{0}
\newcommand{\currentgroupname}{}
\newcommand{\tablealignment}{}
\newcommand{\elementnumberrow}{}
\newcommand{\groupnamesrow}{}
\newcommand{\oldgroupnamesrow}{}
\newcommand{\currentgroupnamesrow}{}    

\newcommand{\newgrouping}[1]{#1 starts.\\
\setcounter{ElementsInGroup}{0}
\addtocounter{GroupNumber}{1}
\renewcommand{\currentgroupname}{#1}
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\oldgroupnamesrow\expandafter{\groupnamesrow}
}
\newcommand{\newelement}{Element \theElements.\\
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\elementnumberrow\expandafter{\elementnumberrow \ifnum\theElements=1{}\else&\fi \theElements}
\addtocounter{ElementsInGroup}{1}
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\currentgroupnamesrow\expandafter{\theElementsInGroup \currentgroupname} % !!
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\groupnamesrow\expandafter{\oldgroupnamesrow \ifnum\theGroupNumber=1{}\else,\fi \currentgroupnamesrow} % need to replace , with &
\expandafter\def\expandafter\tablealignment\expandafter{\tablealignment x|}
\addtocounter{Elements}{1}}    

\begin{document}
\newgrouping{Some}
\newelement
\newelement
\newgrouping{Stuff}
\newelement
\newelement
\newelement
\newgrouping{Here}
\newelement    


\groupnamesrow % prints 2Some,3Stuff,1Here    

\begin{tabular}{|\expand\tablealignment}
\hline
\elementnumberrow \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Some} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Stuff} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Here} 
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}    


\end{document}
```

The problem is that, as soon as I add `\multicolumn` to the line with the `!!`-comment, I receive the error "undefined control sequence \newelement". I had similar problems when I tried to use tabularx for the first version of the table.

After reading some posts, I wonder if it is simply not possible to use multicolumn or tabularx in this context, where `\edef` is needed? If that is true, maybe there is some other way to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Try `\xdef` instead of `\edef` -- your `\edef'ed` command is hidden in the group which is formed by the table cells, so `\newelement` is invisible outside

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Changing the critical line to `\expandafter\xdef\expandafter\currentgroupnamesrow\expandafter{\multicolumn{\theElementsInGroup}{c}{\currentgroupname} } % !!` produces the same error (also when I replace other `\edef`s with `\xdef`). But if I remove `\multicolumn` it works, as with `\edef`, it just doesn't produce what I need.

Comment: I have no time to do this, but I recommend the usage of `expl3` features for this. It seems to be easier.

Comment: That is a good hint. I think I can get it to work with `expl3` features (I have never used them before). I'm going to answer again when it's (hopefully) working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Christian, I have used `expl3` features to solve my problem. I haven't been able to find a way to generate the second version of the table, but since the first version is my favorite anyway, that is not a problem.

There are certainly more elegant ways of solving this than my solution. In particular, I generate a string that contains alignment and content of the cells I want to create first, which I then parse using `expl3` features to generate the row with fitting `tabularx`s, which is overly complicated. However, in my application, I also have to store the data like this - [Using later defined macro values](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248076/using-later-defined-macro-values) - and I'm not sure how to do that with `expl3` sequences.

I have also found this very helpful: [How can I combine \seq_use:Nn and \seq_map_inline:Nn?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169422/how-can-i-combine-seq-usenn-and-seq-map-inlinenn) but I couldn't find a way to produce multicolumns using elements from two sequences instead of just one, which is why I wasn't able to produce the second version of my table.

This is my code for the first version:

```
\documentclass{article}    

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}    

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}    

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{\expand}{}
\long\@namedef{NC@rewrite@\string\expand}{\expandafter\NC@find}
\makeatother    

\newcounter{Elements}
\setcounter{Elements}{1}
\newcounter{ElementsInGroup}
\setcounter{ElementsInGroup}{0}
\newcounter{GroupNumber}
\setcounter{GroupNumber}{0}
\newcommand{\currenttabularxalignment}{}
\newcommand{\currentgroupelements}{}
\newcommand{\elementrowstring}{moo} % nonsense element, to be removed later
\newcommand{\oldelementrowstring}{}
\newcommand{\groupnamesrow}{}    

\newcommand{\newgrouping}[1]{#1~starts.\\
\addtocounter{GroupNumber}{1}
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\groupnamesrow\expandafter{\groupnamesrow\ifnum\theGroupNumber=1{}\else&\fi#1}
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\oldelementrowstring\expandafter{\elementrowstring}
\renewcommand{\currentgroupelements}{}
\renewcommand{\currenttabularxalignment}{}
\setcounter{ElementsInGroup}{0}
}
\newcommand{\newelement}{Element~\theElements.\\
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\currentgroupelements\expandafter{\currentgroupelements \ifnum\theElementsInGroup=0{}\else&\fi \theElements}
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\currenttabularxalignment\expandafter{\currenttabularxalignment\ifnum\theElementsInGroup=0{}\else|\fi Y} 
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\elementrowstring\expandafter{\oldelementrowstring;\currenttabularxalignment,\currentgroupelements} 
\addtocounter{Elements}{1}
\addtocounter{ElementsInGroup}{1}}    

\begin{document}
\newgrouping{Some}
\newelement
\newelement
\newgrouping{Stuff}
\newelement
\newelement
\newelement
\newgrouping{Here}
\newelement    

% now \elementrowstring looks like
% moo;Y|Y,1&2;Y|Y|Y,3&4&5;Y,6
% and we make a table row from that    

% \renewcommand{\elementrowstring}{moo;Y|Y,1&2;Y|Y|Y,3&4&5;Y,6}    

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_nyxl_groups
\seq_new:N \l_nyxl_groupboth    

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {Nnx} % define \seq_set_split:Nnx that expands the last argument
\seq_set_split:Nnx \l_nyxl_groups { ; } {\elementrowstring}    

\cs_new:Npn \nyxl_elementgroupcell:n #1
{
    & \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_nyxl_groupboth { , } {#1} 
    \seq_get_left:NN \l_nyxl_groupboth \l_tmpa_tl 
    \seq_get_right:NN \l_nyxl_groupboth \l_tmpb_tl
    \begin{tabularx}{2cm}{\expand\l_tmpa_tl} 
    \l_tmpb_tl
    \end{tabularx}
}
\cs_new:Npn \nyxl_elementsrow:
{
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_nyxl_groups \nyxl_elementgroupcell:n
}    

\seq_pop_left:NN \l_nyxl_groups \l_tmpa_tl %pop first nonsense-element    

\begin{tabular}{|c|*{\theGroupNumber}{@{}c@{}|}}
\hline
\textit{Elements} \nyxl_elementsrow: \\
\hline
\textit{Groups} & \groupnamesrow \\
\hline
\end{tabular}    

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: Automaticalls generated table]