# Could somebody help me to get this code running?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I have the following problem.
I have already found a code in this forum.
Unfortunately, when I tried to compile this code, it did not work.
This is the problem from this thread:
[enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164925/is-there-a-tool-to-make-a-complicated-table-like-this-one-auswahlliste-from/673470?noredirect=1#comment1673449_673470)

In response to some questions, it was made very clear to me that I should open a separate question on the existing topic, which I am now doing here.

This is the code I tried to compile, but unfortunately it did not work.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{assessmentTable}{%
\newcommand\ItemTitle       {L\"osungsvariante (Lv) eintragen:}
\newcommand\ItemHeading     {Lv}
\newcommand\AssessmentTitle {Entscheidung}
\newcommand\RemarksTitle    {Bemerkungen (Hinweise, Begr\"undungen)}

\AddCriterion   {A}{Vertr\"aglichkeit gegeben}
\AddCriterion   {B}{Forderungen der Anforderungsliste erf\"ult}
\AddCriterion   {C}{Grunds\"atzlich realisiebar}
\AddCriterion   {D}{Aufwand zul\"assig}
\AddCriterion   {E}{Unmittelbare Sicherheitstechnik gegeben}
\AddCriterion   {F}{Im eigenen Bereich bevorzugt}
}%
1 & + & + & + & ? &   &     & Anzahl er Me{\ss}stellen                  & ? \\
2 & + & - &   &   &   &     & Unterbringung der Masse                   & - \\
3 & - &   &   &   &   &     & Radioaktivit\"at                          & - \\
4 & + & + & + & + &   & (+) & (Weiterentwicklung bisheriger L\"osungen) & + \\
5 & + & + & + & + &   &     &                                           & + \\
6 & - &   &   &   &   &     & Fl\"ussigkeit nicht Leitend               & - \\
7 & + & + & + & + &   &     &                                           & + \\
8 & + & + & + & + &   &     & s.\ Lv 7                                  & +

\end{assessmentTable}
\end{document}
```

Is there anyone who would be so kind and could help me to make this code executable?
I would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Dear Mr Santos, 
thank you for your kind words.
Unfortunately, I have the problem that I do not have such an example.
Of course, I know that such an example is needed.
Unfortunately, I only have this one, which is probably also my problem.
If I may ask you to look at the link above to understand what I am trying to achieve.
I did not get any working code from the answers listed there. 
I am trying to achieve the following.
To get a code that produces the desired result.
 There is a sample in and then a sample out described by a forum member.

Comment: This is the code I am looking for or trying to put together.
I would be very grateful if you could help me!
Kind regards

Comment: Ok. Can you please add the preamble to your code? And show, what the problem is? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the assembled pieces from the [linked solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164980/125871) by Niel de Beaudrap.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pbox,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,fit,intersections}

\newlength\criterionwidth           % width for criterion table columns
\newlength\labelheight              % height for labels for assessment criteria
\newlength\labeldepth               % depth for labels for assessment criteria
\newlength\itemcolwidth             % width for the left-most column
\newlength\criterionlabelskip       % vert. skip between legend and first criterion label
\newlength\criterionlabelindent     % left indend for criterion labels from their columns
\newlength\assessmentdiagtopstretch % vert.dist. upwards to pull top of the diagonal
\newlength\assessmentdiagbotstretch % vert.dist. downwards to pull bottom of the diagonal
\newlength\remarkswidth             % absolute width of remarks column
\newlength\remarksxsep              % inner horiz. separation of remarks from column edge

\setlength\criterionwidth           {1.5em}
\setlength\labelheight              {3ex}
\setlength\labeldepth               {1ex}
\setlength\itemcolwidth             {3em}
\setlength\criterionlabelskip       {2ex}
\setlength\criterionlabelindent     {0ex}
\setlength\assessmentdiagtopstretch {5mm}
\setlength\assessmentdiagbotstretch {2mm}
\setlength\remarkswidth             {80mm}
\setlength\remarksxsep              {1em}

\newcommand\labeltypeface   {\itshape}      % face for description labels in the table
\newcommand\celltypesize    {\footnotesize} % size of evalutation cell contents
\newcommand\remarktypeface  {\small}        % size of remark cell contents

\makeatletter
\newcount\@RemarkCol            % Counter for position of the Remarks column
\newtoks\@CriterionNameToks     % Token list for labels of the criteria to asses
\@CriterionNameToks{}

\newcommand\AddCriterion[2]{%   Macro to define a new criterion column / label
    \edef\@tempa{\the\@CriterionNameToks}%
    \ifx\empty\@tempa\@CriterionNameToks{{#1}/{#2}}\else
       \expandafter\@CriterionNameToks\expandafter{\the\@CriterionNameToks,{#1}/{#2}}
    \fi}

\newenvironment{assessmentTable}[1]{%
    \@CriterionNameToks{}%
    \@RemarkCol=2\relax
    #1%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \expandafter\def\expandafter\@CriterionNames\expandafter{\the\@CriterionNameToks}

        \node (CriterionLegend) [inner sep=1em] {\parbox{\paperwidth}{\CriterionLegend}};

        \coordinate (Criterion-first-anchor) at ($(CriterionLegend.south west) + (0,-\criterionlabelskip)$);
        \def\CriterionAnchor{Criterion-first-anchor}
        \foreach \A/\critLabel in \@CriterionNames {
            \global\advance\@RemarkCol by 1\relax
            \node [anchor=north west, text width=\criterionwidth, minimum height=\labelheight+\labeldepth, inner sep=0pt]
                        (\A-anchor) at (\CriterionAnchor) {};
            \node [anchor=west, text height=\labelheight, text depth=\labeldepth]
                        (\A-label) at  ($(\A-anchor.east) + (\criterionlabelindent,0)$)
                        {\labeltypeface\critLabel};
            \xdef\CriterionAnchor{\A-anchor.south east}%
        }
        \node [anchor=north west, inner xsep=\remarksxsep, inner ysep=0pt, text height=\labelheight, text depth=\labeldepth,
                    text width=\remarkswidth-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}]
                    (Remarks-title) at (\CriterionAnchor)
                    {\labeltypeface\RemarksTitle};

        \node [anchor=south west, minimum height=\itemcolwidth,rotate=90]
                    (ItemTitle) at (Remarks-title.north -| CriterionLegend.west)
                    {\ItemTitle};
        \node [inner sep=0pt, fit=(ItemTitle)(ItemTitle |- CriterionLegend.north)]
                    (ItemTitle) {};

        \def\CriterionAnchor{ItemTitle.west}
        \node [anchor=north west, text height=\labelheight, text depth=\labeldepth, inner ysep=0pt]
                    (ItemHeading) at (ItemTitle.south west)  {\ItemHeading};

        \foreach \A/\critLabel in \@CriterionNames {%
            \node [inner sep=0pt, anchor=south, minimum width=\criterionwidth, text height=\labelheight, text depth=\labeldepth]
                        (\A-heading) at (ItemHeading.south -| \A-anchor)  {\A};
        }
        \node [anchor=north west, rotate=90, minimum height=\criterionwidth, inner ysep=0pt]
                    (AssessmentTitle) at (Remarks-title.south east)  {\AssessmentTitle};
        \node [inner sep=0pt, fit=(AssessmentTitle)] (AssessmentTitle)  {};
        \node [anchor=north east]
                    (AssessmentLegend) at (CriterionLegend.north -| AssessmentTitle.east) 
                    {\pbox{\paperwidth}{\AssessmentLegend}};

        \def\@GridFinalRow{0}

        \matrix [%
                anchor=north west, matrix of nodes,%
                nodes in empty cells,
                inner sep=0pt,
                nodes={%
                    draw=white, inner sep=0pt,
                    execute at begin node=\celltypesize$,
                    execute at end node=$\xdef\@GridFinalRow{\pgfmatrixcurrentrow},\iffalse$ Fix some syntax hilighting problems\fi
                    text height=3ex, text depth=1ex, minimum width=\criterionwidth},
                column 1/.style={%
                    execute at begin node=\expandafter\@gobble\@gobble,
                    execute at end node=\@gobble,
                    nodes={minimum width=\itemcolwidth}},
                column \the\@RemarkCol/.style={%
                    execute at begin node=\remarktypeface\expandafter\@gobble\@gobble,
                    execute at end node=\@gobble,
                    nodes={%
                        minimum width=\remarkswidth,
                        inner xsep=\remarksxsep,
                        text width=\remarkswidth-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}}
        ] (Grid) at (ItemHeading.south west)
        \bgroup
}{%
        \\ \egroup;

        \expandafter\ifnum\@GridFinalRow>0
            \foreach \row in {1,...,\@GridFinalRow} {%
                \draw (Grid-\row-1.south west) -- (Grid-\row-1.south west -| Grid.east);
            }
        \fi

        \draw (ItemTitle.north west)    -- (AssessmentLegend.north east)
                                                                    -- (AssessmentTitle.south east)
                                                                    -- (ItemHeading.south west) -- cycle;
        \draw (Grid.north east) -- (Grid.south east) -- (Grid.south west) -- (Grid.north west);                                                             
        \draw (CriterionLegend.north west) -- (Criterion-first-anchor);

        \draw [name path=AssessmentLegendBoundary]
                    (AssessmentLegend.north west) -- ($(AssessmentLegend.south west) + (0mm,\assessmentdiagtopstretch)$)
                                                                                -- ($(AssessmentTitle.north west) + (0mm,-\assessmentdiagbotstretch)$)
                                                                                -- (AssessmentTitle.south west |- Grid.south);

        \path [name path=Remarks-north-boundary] (Remarks-title.north west) -- ($(Remarks-title.north east) + (\paperwidth,0mm)$);
        \path [name intersections={of=AssessmentLegendBoundary and Remarks-north-boundary, by={Remarks-north-east-boundary}}];
        \draw (Remarks-north-east-boundary) -- (Remarks-title.north west) -- (Remarks-title.north west |- Grid.south);

        \foreach \A/\critLabel in \@CriterionNames {%
            \path [name path=\A-north-boundary] (\A-anchor.north west) -- ($(\A-anchor.north east) + (\paperwidth,0mm)$);
            \path [name intersections={of=AssessmentLegendBoundary and \A-north-boundary, by={\A-north-east-boundary}}];
            \draw (\A-north-east-boundary) -- (\A-anchor.north west) -- (\A-anchor.north west |- Grid.south);
        }       
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\CriterionLegend{%
%
        L\"osungsvariante {( Lv )} nach \\
        \underline{\MakeUppercase{Auswahlkriterien}} beurteilen: \\[2ex]
        \begin{tabular}{@{(}c@{)\quad}l}
          $+$   &   ja
        \\
            $-$ &   nein
        \\
            ?   &   Informationsmangel
        \\
            ! & Anforderungliste \"uberpr\"ufen
        \end{tabular}
%
}

\newcommand\AssessmentLegend{%
%
        \begin{tabular}{c@{\quad}l}
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{\MakeUppercase{Entscheiden}}
        \\
        \hline
                    &   L\"osungsvarianten (Lv) \\ & kennzeichnen:
        \\[2ex]
            ($+$)   &   L\"osung weiter verfolgen
        \\
            ($-$)   &   L\"osung scheidet aus
        \\
            (?)     & Information beschaffen \\& (L\"osung erneut beurteilen)
        \\
            (!)     &   Anforderungliste auf \\& \"Anderung pr\"ufen
        \end{tabular}
%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{assessmentTable}{%
    \newcommand\ItemTitle       {L\"osungsvariante (Lv) eintragen:}
    \newcommand\ItemHeading     {Lv}
    \newcommand\AssessmentTitle {Entscheidung}
    \newcommand\RemarksTitle    {Bemerkungen (Hinweise, Begr\"undungen)}

    \AddCriterion   {A}{Vertr\"aglichkeit gegeben}
    \AddCriterion   {B}{Forderungen der Anforderungsliste erf\"ult}
    \AddCriterion   {C}{Grunds\"atzlich realisiebar}
    \AddCriterion   {D}{Aufwand zul\"assig}
    \AddCriterion   {E}{Unmittelbare Sicherheitstechnik gegeben}
    \AddCriterion   {F}{Im eigenen Bereich bevorzugt}
}%
    1 & + & + & + & ? &   &     & Anzahl er Me{\ss}stellen                  & ? \\
    2 & + & - &   &   &   &     & Unterbringung der Masse                   & - \\
    3 & - &   &   &   &   &     & Radioaktivit\"at                          & - \\
    4 & + & + & + & + &   & (+) & (Weiterentwicklung bisheriger L\"osungen) & + \\
    5 & + & + & + & + &   &     &                                           & + \\
    6 & - &   &   &   &   &     & Fl\"ussigkeit nicht Leitend               & - \\
    7 & + & + & + & + &   &     &                                           & + \\
    8 & + & + & + & + &   &     & s.\ Lv 7                                  & +
\end{assessmentTable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much!  You saved the day!

Comment: @Protonlaser If the answer suits with you, please accept it by clicking the `tick` mark